# jetty continuation and unexplainable memory usage pattern

Tags: memory-leaks, jetty, continuations

I have been struggling with something that looks very basic, the problem is related to use of Jetty continuations for long poll.

For the sake of simplicity, i have removed all my application specific code and just left simple continuation related code.

I am pasting the doPost method of my servlet below. The key question, where i need some expert guidance is

- In the code block below, if i run it as is and fire post requests which carry a post body of approx 200 bytes then the amount of memory for 500 long poll connections is around 20 MB.
- Where as if I comment the block highlighted as "decrease memory footprint :: comment block below" then the memory foot print comes down to 7 MB

In both the cases i wait for system to be stable, call GC multiple times and then take memory reading via jConsole. Its not exact, but the difference is so much and explanable that precision of few 100 bytes here or there does not matter.

My problem explodes, considering my server is required to hold 100K connections if not more. And here and this unexplanable increase in size eventually leads to close to GBs of extra heap used.

( what is causing this extra heap usage, when even what is read from the stream is not preserved outside the scope of doPost method. But still it adds to the heap....what am i missing?)

```
   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Continuation cc = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(req);

    //if continuation is resumed, then send an answer back with 
    //hardcoded answer
    if (cc.isResumed()) {
        String myJson = "{\"1\",\"2\"}";
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.setContentLength(myJson.length());
        PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
        writer.write(myJson);
        writer.close();
    } 
    // if it is the first call to doPost ( not reentrant call )
    else if (cc.isInitial()) {          

        //START :: decrease memory footprint :: comment this block :: START

        // store the json from the request body in a string
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;                      
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(line);
        }  

        //here jsonString was parsed and some values extracted
        //though that code is removed for the sake of this publish
        // as problem exists irrespective...of any processing

        line = null;            
        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedReader = null;
        jsonString = null;

        // END :: decrease memory footprint :: comment this block :: END

        cc.setTimeout(150000);        

        cc.suspend();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is causing this extra heap usage...

Take a look at this line:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = req.getReader();
```

Note that you are not actually creating a new BufferedReader.  When you call `getBufferedReader`, Jetty creates a BufferedReader which wraps an InputStreamReader which wraps a custom InputStream implementation which wraps a byte buffer.  I am pretty sure that by executing the code which reads the entire message, you create large byte buffer inside the request object which stores the entire contents of the message body.  Plus the request object maintains a reference to the readers.

At the beginning of the function you called:

```
Continuation cc = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(req);
```

I believe your continuation is holding onto the request which is storing all the data.  So the simple act of reading the data is allocating the memory which will be preserved until you `discontinue` your continuation.

One thing you might try just as an experiment.  Change your code to:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
```

This way Jetty won't allocate it's own readers.  Again - I don't know how much data is really stored in the readers compared to the rest of the request object - but it might help a little.

[update]

Another alternative is to avoid the problem.  That's what I did (although I was using servlet 3.0 rather than Continuations).  I had a resource - let's call it `/transfer` which would POST some data, then use an `AsyncContext` to wait for a response.  I changed it to two requests with different URLS - `/push` and `/pull`.  Any time I had some content that needed to be sent from client to server, it would go in the `/push` request which would then immediately return without creating an `AsyncContext`.  Thus, any storage in the request is freed up right away.  Then to wait for the response, I sent a second GET request with no message body.  Sure - the request hangs around for a while - but who cares - it does not have any content.

You may have to rethink your problem and determine if you can perform your task in pieces - multiple requests - or whether you really have to handle everything in a single request.

Comment: thanks, i would try your recommendation....in the mean while i tried reading from ServletInputStream ( which is very much on the lines that you pointed to)  and it improved the situation drastically. What i dont understand is that when i read from reader once the data is read and stored into a String within the method scope why is the object kept in memory till the continuation object is cleaned. Scope of all my Strings is doPost...so whats read from the stream/input or reader should be cleaned after the doPost except what i keep on continuation.I know i am wrong somewhere...but not sure where

Comment: i have accepted the answer, though i continued other ways. I tried my own server based on netty. And in that case i could release the memory after the read is over from incoming connection...so i think it is something in the way Jetty works...ideally once someone suspends continuation he should have an option that he is done with the request option and only thing left is sending a response. So the resources / buffers whatever on request object shall be released. ( would try some jetty specific forums to have that thread, though i am putting this text justincase for future readers of this Q)

Comment: have created a topic on jetty forum, incase a future reader wants to track...am adding link http://jetty.4.n6.nabble.com/Jetty-Continuations-Long-poll-and-release-of-request-object-td4959635.html

Comment: the spec is not controlled my my app entirely, and the clients are third party in some cases...so splitting is not an easy option ( for non tech reasons ). I am more convinced on creating a app from scratch using Netty ( as my tests show much better results on memory consumption even for plain socket that i am holding, in jetty case as continuation object and in netty case channel. Its around 13K Vs 4K bytes ). And my needs are not very agressive on servlet container part except ease of deployment which i would find some workaround....most likely